# Laravel drop down list save data using one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

hello how to save the value from a drop-down-list i'm using blade and the drop-down-list data is from another table i'm using one to many relationship but i can't save the value to my controller

Note: I can't save the value of the following: **Student_id,Classes_id,Level_id**

**Controller**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request, [


        'accountname'=>'required|max:50',
        'Student_id'=>'required|max:50',
        'Level_id'=>'required|max:50',
        'Classes_id'=>'required|max:50',
        'status'=>'required|max:50',

            ]);


            $accounts = new Account();
            $accounts->accountname = $request->accountname;
            $accounts->Student_id = $request->Student_id;
            $accounts->Level_id = $request->Level_id;
            $accounts->Classes_id = $request->Classes_id;
            $accounts->status = $request->status;
            $accounts->save();

  //Display a successful message upon save
    return redirect()->route('accounts.index')
        ->with('flash_message', 'Success.');
}
```

**View-Blade**

```html
<form action="{{route('accounts.store')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}

<div class="form-group">
<label for="accountname">School Year</label>
<input type="text" name="accountname" id="accountname" value="{{old('accountname')}}" placeholder="Enter SCHOOLYEAR" class="form-control" required>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>STUDENT</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Student_id" name="Student_id"  >
<option value="N/A" dissable="true" selected="true">--SELECT--</option>
@foreach($students as $student)
    <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->studentname}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label>Level</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Level_id" name="Level_id">
<option value="N/A" dissable="true" selected="true">--SELECT--</option>
@foreach($levels as $level)
    <option value="{{$level->id}}">{{$level->levelname}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Class</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Classes_id" name="Classes_id">
<option value="N/A" dissable="true" selected="true">--SELECT--</option>
@foreach($classes as $class)
    <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->classname}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Status</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
<option value="N/A" dissable="true" selected="true">--SELECT--</option>
<option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
<option value="WITHDRAW">WITHDRAW</option>
<option value="GRADUATE">GRADUATE</option>
</select>
</div>

<div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button></div>
</form>
```

Please Let me know Which part should i Edit

Comment: Do you have any error ? what are you asking for :D

Comment: In Controller please debug and print $_POST variables, and see are you gettting Student_id,Level_id and Classes_id

Comment: Show the migration for the `account` table

Comment: dissable="true" selected="true", dont think its necessary.

Answer (score 1):

@ Sagar Gautam

fix it thanks but how to display the name instead of id into my Index?

```html
<h1><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Enroll List</h1>
    
        <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Student</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($accounts as $account)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $account->accountname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $account->Student_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $account->Level_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $account->Classes_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $account->status }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
       
        <div><a href="{{route('accounts.create')}}" class="btn btn-success">Add Student <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a></div>
     
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dissable="true" selected="true"` from your `option` tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>STUDENT</label>
 <select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Student_id" name="Student_id"  >
    <option value="N/A">--SELECT--</option>
    @foreach($students as $student)
    <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->studentname}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label>Level</label>
 <select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Level_id" name="Level_id">
  <option value="N/A">--SELECT--</option>
  @foreach($levels as $level)
   <option value="{{$level->id}}">{{$level->levelname}}</option>
  @endforeach
 </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Class</label>
 <select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="Classes_id" name="Classes_id">
  <option value="N/A">--SELECT--</option>
  @foreach($classes as $class)
   <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->classname}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Status</label>
  <select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
   <option value="N/A">--SELECT--</option>
   <option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
   <option value="WITHDRAW">WITHDRAW</option>
   <option value="GRADUATE">GRADUATE</option>
  </select>
</div>
```